# UISplitView - Replacing DetailView with an animation

Tags: ios, animation, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller

I was wondering if I can replace detailView with an animation. At the moment I have some buttons in the MasterView and I use those buttons to replace the detailView with different views.. Can I animate this? Thanks..

Comment: yes you can animate this what did you have in mind?

Comment: not sure.. a simple animation to show that view has been changed..? by the way I am using storyboards..